# MySQL - Trying to retrieve recent posts in database using a for loop - shows only the first post

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

- I'm am trying to retrieve top 3 recent posts in MySQL database and
  post them in separate DIV using for loop.
- Each post should show only show first 300 characters.
- However it shows only the first post (300 characters) in all three
  DIV.

Here is the code:

```
   <!--- HTML CODE HERE --!> 
   <?php
    for($i = 1; $i<=3; $i++) {
    ?>
      <div id="outer-box">
        <div id="postImage-wrapper">
          image
        </div>
        <div id="postContent-wrapper">
          <h3> This is an Example post </h3>
          <span id="postInfo-wrapper">Author | 22/10/2015 | Xbox | 3 Comments</span><br />
          <?php
          $result = doSql("SELECT `gamereviews`.`reviewContent` FROM `gamereviews` ORDER BY `gamereviews`.`dateOfReview` DESC LIMIT 3");
          $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
          echo '<div onclick="alert(\''.$row[0].'\');">'.substr($row[0], 0, 300).'</div>';
          ?>
          <!-- <p class="post-snippet">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
            type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries five centuries.</p> -->
        </div>

        <div id="postRating-wrapper">
          7.7
        </div>
      </div>


  <?php
    }
    ?>
```

**Here is the result:**
https://gyazo.com/5593b4a4ccd82b61e88e8af90dedbe2f

**I realize that the problem is probably with my for loop, that is, it simply prints out the first post 3 times.**

But what is the way around this, how can I retrieve 3 posts from database and print them out in each div using a `for loop` or (if there is a better way)?

Answer (score 0):

`Actually you are running the query inside the **for loop**  , that's why you are getting the wrong result. first of all run the query outside the loop and then run a **for each** loop on the returned array.

Comment: Can you give an example to clarify what you mean please?